# How to transform a column with many variables into separate variable columns

Tags: stata

I provide a simple version of my dataset at the end.

Given a Time, I have for every Activity values for the nine different subjects.
I want to achieve that the Subject column is transformed into 9 new variables, such that I have the following structure:

Time, Activity, Subject 1, Subject 2,...., Subject 9

Where the Subject variables contain the corresponding entries of Value.

So at the end I want to have for every point of Time, the 8 Activities and

```
 Time | ACTIVITY | Subject1 | Subject2 | ... | Subject9
    -----| ---------|----------|----------|-----|----------
    1995 | A        | example  | example  |     | example
    1995 | F        | example  | example  |     | example
    1995 | K        | example  | example  |     | example
    1995 | J        | example  | example  |     | example
```

`...`

I already tried the `reshape` command, 
`reshape wide ACTIVITY, i(Value) j(Subject) string` but I suspect that `reshape` isn´t the correct command here to obtain the result I want.

```
clear
input int Time str55 Subject str3 ACTIVITY str18 Value
1995 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "A"   "-2.426848"         
1995 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "A"   "19.235807"         
1995 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "A"   "16.342135"         
1995 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "A"   "-8.435628"         
1995 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "A"   "-7.921433"         
1995 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "A"   "4.14512"           
1995 "Total hours worked"                                      "A"   "1.617676"          
1995 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "A"   "-22.776078"        
1995 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "A"   "-21.297326"        
1995 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "F"   "-1.653278"         
1995 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "F"   "1.703939"          
1995 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "F"   ".02249"            
1995 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "F"   "2.544764"          
1995 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "F"   "3.459858"          
1995 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "F"   "1.784137"          
1995 "Total hours worked"                                      "F"   ".101362"           
1995 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "F"   "1.726501"          
1995 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "F"   "2.521708"          
1995 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "K"   "1.694564"          
1995 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "K"   "1.221264"          
1995 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "K"   "2.936522"          
1995 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "K"   "9.752344000000001" 
1995 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "K"   "7.939534"          
1995 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "K"   "1.113274"          
1995 "Total hours worked"                                      "K"   "2.826703"          
1995 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "K"   "6.637213"          
1995 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "K"   "6.621383"          
1995 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "J"   "1.271221"          
1995 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "J"   ".416748"           
1995 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "J"   "1.693267"          
1995 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "J"   "6.733944"          
1995 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "J"   "4.750437"          
1995 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "J"   "3.961272"          
1995 "Total hours worked"                                      "J"   "5.28285"           
1995 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "J"   "4.315704"          
1995 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "J"   "4.956746"          
1995 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "C"   "-.961265"          
1995 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "C"   "3.918341"          
1995 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "C"   "2.919411"          
1995 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "C"   "9.327536"          
1995 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "C"   "10.142572"         
1995 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "C"   "-.615951"          
1995 "Total hours worked"                                      "C"   "-1.571295"         
1995 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "C"   "5.989541"          
1995 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "C"   "6.226353"          
1995 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "BDE" ".052094"           
1995 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "BDE" "9.885144"          
1995 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "BDE" "9.942387"          
1995 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "BDE" "13.808441"         
1995 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "BDE" "12.406663"         
1995 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "BDE" "-3.86639"          
1995 "Total hours worked"                                      "BDE" "-3.81631"          
1995 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "BDE" "2.294686"          
1995 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "BDE" "3.516435"          
1995 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "MN"  ".131723"           
1995 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "MN"  "-6.173118"         
1995 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "MN"  "-6.049526"         
1995 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "MN"  ".8593380000000001" 
1995 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "MN"  ".451672"           
1995 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "MN"  "7.730918"          
1995 "Total hours worked"                                      "MN"  "7.872824"          
1995 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "MN"  "7.060652"          
1995 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "MN"  "7.35373"           
1995 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "G_I" "-1.07602"          
1995 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "G_I" "4.234882"          
1995 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "G_I" "3.113293"          
1995 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "G_I" "3.355356"          
1995 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "G_I" "3.935881"          
1995 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "G_I" "2.40757"           
1995 "Total hours worked"                                      "G_I" "1.305644"          
1995 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "G_I" "-.286853"          
1995 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "G_I" ".234754"           
1996 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "A"   "2.25265"           
1996 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "A"   "5.369203"          
1996 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "A"   "7.742802"          
1996 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "A"   "10.454575"         
1996 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "A"   "5.366434"          
1996 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "A"   ".451591"           
1996 "Total hours worked"                                      "A"   "2.714414"          
1996 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "A"   "-.002628"          
1996 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "A"   "2.516895"          
1996 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "F"   "1.728397"          
1996 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "F"   "3.759875"          
1996 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "F"   "5.553258"          
1996 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "F"   "5.375732"          
1996 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "F"   "1.426935"          
1996 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "F"   "-2.600872"         
1996 "Total hours worked"                                      "F"   "-.9174290000000001"
1996 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "F"   "-2.248403"         
1996 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "F"   "-.168186"          
1996 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "K"   "-.480611"          
1996 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "K"   "7.184181"          
1996 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "K"   "6.669043"          
1996 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "K"   "7.474571"          
1996 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "K"   "7.808084"          
1996 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "K"   ".219797"           
1996 "Total hours worked"                                      "K"   "-.26187"           
1996 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "K"   ".582085"           
1996 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "K"   ".755166"           
1996 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "J"   "1.146989"          
1996 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "J"   "2.294382"          
1996 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "J"   "3.467687"          
1996 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "J"   "-.888716"          
1996 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "J"   "-1.391543"         
1996 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "J"   "3.804509"          
1996 "Total hours worked"                                      "J"   "4.995135"          
1996 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "J"   "-3.603252"         
1996 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "J"   "-4.2104"           
1996 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "C"   ".127422"           
1996 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "C"   ".390807"           
1996 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "C"   ".5187270000000001" 
1996 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "C"   "-.219582"          
1996 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "C"   "-.44278"           
1996 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "C"   "1.171237"          
1996 "Total hours worked"                                      "C"   "1.300151"          
1996 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "C"   "-.830342"          
1996 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "C"   "-.734499"          
1996 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "BDE" "-.10856"           
1996 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "BDE" "8.380025"          
1996 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "BDE" "8.262368"          
1996 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "BDE" "6.231358"          
1996 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "BDE" "7.102013"          
1996 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "BDE" "-7.014769"         
1996 "Total hours worked"                                      "BDE" "-7.115713"         
1996 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "BDE" "-1.179195"         
1996 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "BDE" "-1.876007"         
1996 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "MN"  "-.353884"          
1996 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "MN"  "1.076035"          
1996 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "MN"  ".718343"           
1996 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "MN"  "1.12435"           
1996 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "MN"  "1.117737"          
1996 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "MN"  "3.155591"          
1996 "Total hours worked"                                      "MN"  "2.790539"          
1996 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "MN"  ".041258"           
1996 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "MN"  ".403111"           
1996 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "G_I" "-.798141"          
1996 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "G_I" "4.965412"          
1996 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "G_I" "4.127639"          
1996 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "G_I" "10.194463"         
1996 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "G_I" "10.477853"         
1996 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "G_I" ".885576"           
1996 "Total hours worked"                                      "G_I" ".080367"           
1996 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "G_I" "5.251674"          
1996 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "G_I" "5.826333"          
1997 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "A"   ".731776"           
1997 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "A"   "-3.186056"         
1997 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "A"   "-2.477594"         
1997 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "A"   "-5.06916"          
1997 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "A"   "-6.890363"         
1997 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "A"   "2.698438"          
1997 "Total hours worked"                                      "A"   "3.44996"           
1997 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "A"   "-3.826213"         
1997 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "A"   "-2.657405"         
1997 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "F"   "2.117396"          
1997 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "F"   "5.906121"          
1997 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "F"   "8.148573000000001" 
1997 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "F"   "1.279112"          
1997 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "F"   "1.322872"          
1997 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "F"   "1.8041"            
1997 "Total hours worked"                                      "F"   "3.959696"          
1997 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "F"   "-4.327652"         
1997 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "F"   "-6.351874"         
1997 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "K"   ".43239"            
1997 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "K"   "8.700056999999999" 
1997 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "K"   "9.170064999999999" 
1997 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "K"   "11.205117"         
1997 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "K"   "11.399443"         
1997 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "K"   "-1.822407"         
1997 "Total hours worked"                                      "K"   "-1.397898"         
1997 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "K"   "2.483335"          
1997 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "K"   "1.864112"          
1997 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "J"   "-3.236768"         
1997 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "J"   "21.34373"          
1997 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "J"   "17.416115"         
1997 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "J"   "14.072785"         
1997 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "J"   "18.627454"         
1997 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "J"   "-7.862875"         
1997 "Total hours worked"                                      "J"   "-10.84514"         
1997 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "J"   "-2.238497"         
1997 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "J"   "-2.84742"          
1997 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "C"   ".198729"           
1997 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "C"   "3.620337"          
1997 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "C"   "3.826261"          
1997 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "C"   "4.423006"          
1997 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "C"   "4.697621"          
1997 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "C"   "-.840977"          
1997 "Total hours worked"                                      "C"   "-.643919"          
1997 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "C"   "1.039645"          
1997 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "C"   ".574753"           
1997 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "BDE" "1.753725"          
1997 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "BDE" "4.57343"           
1997 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "BDE" "6.40736"           
1997 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "BDE" ".474943"           
1997 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "BDE" "-.653428"          
1997 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "BDE" "-2.690283"         
1997 "Total hours worked"                                      "BDE" "-.983739"          
1997 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "BDE" "-4.998266"         
1997 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "BDE" "-5.575195"         
1997 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "MN"  ".420778"           
1997 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "MN"  "-1.055989"         
1997 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "MN"  "-.639655"          
1997 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "MN"  "5.067928"          
1997 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "MN"  "4.630638"          
1997 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "MN"  "7.493905"          
1997 "Total hours worked"                                      "MN"  "7.946215"          
1997 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "MN"  "5.747318"          
1997 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "MN"  "5.744327"          
1997 "Average hours worked per person employed"                "G_I" ".532551"           
1997 "Gross value added per hour worked, constant prices"      "G_I" "3.058326"          
1997 "Gross value added per person employed, constant prices " "G_I" "3.607164"          
1997 "Labour compensation per employee "                       "G_I" "2.245979"          
1997 "Labour compensation per hour worked"                     "G_I" "2.114407"          
1997 "Total employment (number of persons employed)"           "G_I" ".621482"           
1997 "Total hours worked"                                      "G_I" "1.157342"          
1997 "Unit Labour Costs"                                       "G_I" "-.9159080000000001"
1997 "Unit Labour Costs, employment based "                    "G_I" "-1.313795"         
end
```

Comment: Screenshots are of very limited use: readers have go back and forth between a screenshot and a question and can't copy and paste into their Stata.  Please post an explicit data example. `dataex` (SSC; install with `ssc inst dataex`) will help. We can't comment on your `reshape` command because you don't give the code. Please study http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for the edits. The `reshape` command was wrong for these data. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Stata, columns are columns of matrices. What you call columns are **variables**.

Your screenshot shows the following problems:

1. Your `Time` variable and `Value` variable are string. That looks wrong. There is probably some garbage somewhere in those variables. Perhaps headers have been copied into the data. `list Time if missing(real(Time))` is the kind of command that will show you non-numeric values.
2. Your `Subject` variable shows trailing spaces. That could cause problems if it's not consistent.
3. Your `Subject` variable's distinct values couldn't be parts of variable names given the embedded spaces. So, we need some extra work.

This code generates a toy example and shows some technique. Contrary to your guess, `reshape` is the command of choice.

```
clear 
set obs 6 
gen location = "AUS" 
gen time = 1995 
gen subject = cond(mod(_n, 2), "Fooling around ", " Wasting time") 
gen activity = word("A F K", ceil(_n/2)) 
gen value = _n 
replace subject = trim(subject) 
list 

     +-----------------------------------------------------+
     | location   time          subject   activity   value |
     |-----------------------------------------------------|
  1. |      AUS   1995   Fooling around          A       1 |
  2. |      AUS   1995     Wasting time          A       2 |
  3. |      AUS   1995   Fooling around          F       3 |
  4. |      AUS   1995     Wasting time          F       4 |
  5. |      AUS   1995   Fooling around          K       5 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------|
  6. |      AUS   1995     Wasting time          K       6 |
     +-----------------------------------------------------+


egen group = group(subject), label 
su group, meanonly 
local gmax = r(max) 
forval g = 1/`gmax' { 
    local lbl`g' "`: label (group) `g''" 
} 
drop subject 

reshape wide value, i(location time activity) j(group) 

forval g = 1/`gmax' { 
   label var value`g' "`lbl`g''" 
} 
list 

     +----------------------------------------------+
     | location   time   activity   value1   value2 |
     |----------------------------------------------|
  1. |      AUS   1995          A        1        2 |
  2. |      AUS   1995          F        3        4 |
  3. |      AUS   1995          K        5        6 |
     +----------------------------------------------+

describe 


Contains data
  obs:             3                          
 vars:             5                          
 size:            60 (99.9% of memory free)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage  display     value
variable name   type   format      label      variable label
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
location        str3   %9s                    
time            float  %9.0g                  
activity        str1   %9s                    
value1          float  %9.0g                  Fooling around
value2          float  %9.0g                  Wasting time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by:  location  time  activity
```